# How to get full tweet text?

Tags: json, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

Right now the line status.text is getting the tweet text but it is truncated (not the full tweet text). How can I get the full text of the tweet by using on status when getting information about tweets?

```
def on_status(self, status):

    if not hasattr(status,'retweeted_status'):

        #db = DatabaseInteractor.DatabaseInteractor()

        text=self.parse_text(status.text)
        created_at=self.parse_text(status.created_at)
        user_id=self.parse_text(status.user.id_str)
        username=self.parse_text(status.user.name)
        location=self.parse_text(status.user.location)
        coordinates=self.parse_text(status.coordinates)
        tweet_id=self.parse_text(status.id_str)
        hashtags=self.parse_text(status.entities['hashtags'])

        print("Created At: " + created_at)
        print("Tweet Text: "  + text)
        print("Tweet ID: " + tweet_id)
        print("Username: " + username)
        print("Username ID: " + user_id)
        print("Location: " + location )
        print("Coordinates: " + coordinates)
        print("Hashtags: " + hashtags)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using the Twitter Streaming API (`statuses/filter`, or a `StreamListener` in tweepy).

In that case, if a Tweet has a field that states `truncated: true`, you need to look for an additional field in the Tweet object called `extended_tweet`, which will contain a field called `full_text`.

The `tweet_mode='extended'` parameter suggested in the previous answer is not valid on the Streaming API.

In Twitter Developer Labs (the next version of the API currently being tested) there is no longer a distincion between truncated or extended Tweets, and all Tweet objects will return the full text data.

Answer (score 0):

[Taking reference from here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/974)

if you want to get full-text on Twitter response, you need to add a keyword tweet_mode='extended' when calling API like this:

`api.search(q='<something to search keyword>', tweet_mode='extended')`

By adding this keyword, you can get full_text field in the response from the API, instead of text field, Also note some tweets may not have extended text and will give an error so use `try and except`

```py
def on_status(self, status):

    if not hasattr(status,'retweeted_status'):

        #db = DatabaseInteractor.DatabaseInteractor()

        try:    
            text=self.parse_text(status.retweeted_status.extended_tweet['full_text']) #Replace text with extended_tweet['full_text']
        except:
            text=self.parse_text(status.retweeted_status.text)

        created_at=self.parse_text(status.created_at)
        user_id=self.parse_text(status.user.id_str)
        username=self.parse_text(status.user.name)
        location=self.parse_text(status.user.location)
        coordinates=self.parse_text(status.coordinates)
        tweet_id=self.parse_text(status.id_str)
        hashtags=self.parse_text(status.entities['hashtags'])

        print("Created At: " + created_at)
        print("Tweet Text: "  + text)
        print("Tweet ID: " + tweet_id)
        print("Username: " + username)
        print("Username ID: " + user_id)
        print("Location: " + location )
        print("Coordinates: " + coordinates)
        print("Hashtags: " + hashtags)
```